# Is it possible to show a 'div' content on an image "mouse over" using RJS Template? If so or not, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mouseevent, rjs

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to have an image that responds to a 'mouseover' event to load and show an HTML 'div' content, just how you can see passing the mouse arrow over a tag present in Stackoverflow.com.

I prefer to use the RJS Template, but I don't know if it is possible using this. I will appreciate if you make me a real example including some codes and explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definitely avoid rjs (I never liked it) and go for JS directly:

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

```
$('img').mouseenter(function() {
   $('#my_div').append('<div>Some stuff that need to appear</div>');
});
```

cheers.